# What tools can be used to automate testing on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: automated-testing, tools, browser-automation, mobile

What frameworks / tools enable to automate testing on Windows Phone 8 platform?

I'm interested in testing of all application types, including:

- Mobile web
- Native apps
- Hybrid apps
- Silverlight apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**All-in-one:**

- [SeeTest](http://experitest.com/)

**Mobile web:**

- [Windows Phone Web Driver](https://winphonewebdriver.codeplex.com/)
- [BridgIt](https://github.com/andrebrov/BridgIt)

**Native apps:**

- [CodedUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn305948.aspx)
- [Winium.StoreApps](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.StoreApps)
- [windows-phone-8-bootstrap](https://github.com/appium/windows-phone-8-bootstrap)

**Hybrid apps:**

- [CodedUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn305948.aspx)
- [Winium.StoreApps.CodedUi](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.StoreApps.CodedUi)

**Silverlight apps:**

- [Windows Phone Driver](https://github.com/2gis/winphonedriver)

> P.S. If you know other solutions, please share. Thank you.